# PHP is_writable returns always FALSE

Tags: php, linux, magento, permissions

Why PHP with the correct permissions on the directory still returning FALSE?

I had tried chmod 777 to the directory that the script says is not writable and chown to root and apache.

```
if (!is_writable($destinationFolder)) {
        throw new Exception('Folder: '.$destinationFolder.' is not writable or does not exists.');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable selinux.

```
# vim /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

Set 'SELINUX=disabled', write it ':wq'. Reboot an start apache again.